# Using aurelia-materialize-bridge with karma testing

Tags: aurelia

I am using aurelia-materialize-bridge with my Aurelia application. It is a UI toolkit. I configured it according to the [Aurelia-Cli installation instructions](https://aurelia-ui-toolkits.gitbooks.io/materialize-bridge-docs/content/installation/aurelia-cli.html) in the guide with some success. Pages load correctly and most components seem to work.

When I run the unit tests `au test`, I get a handfull of 404 errors.

```
19 10 2016 19:51:18.049:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
19 10 2016 19:51:18.065:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
19 10 2016 19:51:19.284:INFO [Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#ONnYj7PlSdj5wYRyAAAA with id 80681297
19 10 2016 19:51:19.510:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/jquery.hammer.js
19 10 2016 19:51:19.511:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/jquery.timeago.js
19 10 2016 19:51:19.512:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/picker.js
19 10 2016 19:51:19.513:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/picker.date.js
19 10 2016 19:51:19.513:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/velocity.js
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery.hammer"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at F:/Oct2016/I Know Sports Too/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3763
```

How can I get past these 404 errors and run tests? The missing scripts all can be found in the materialize-css.js file in the root.

Comment: This is strange. It shouldn't even try to load hammer.js and the others because these are already bundled in materialize-bundle (you should be able to Ctrl-F-find it in the bundle).

As you probably know, the Aurelia-CLI instructions tell to create an AMD compatible version of Materialize. This output is the same as if this didn't happen.

Comment: I've created a new issue to track this:
https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/issues/316
ATM I'm suspecting requirejs path shenanigans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `karma.config.js`, I was added two lines to splice in the materialize-bundle after the entryBundle.

```
let otherBundle = path.join(output, 'materialize-bundle.js');
let entryBundle = appSrc.splice(entryIndex, 1)[0];

let files = [entryBundle, otherBundle].concat(testSrc).concat(appSrc);
```

It sems to work. Post your answers if you've got a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the materialize-bundle (which seems to already be pulled in by project.build.bundles on #12) seems to cause a new problem:

```
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return t(e)}
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
  at c:/Users/shart/Projects/federal-identity/newton/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10423
```

Hopefully someone else out there has experienced this. If anyone finds a solution please post.